# Possible to copy/paste from IPython Notebook to other apps?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Ipython Notebook.  I can cut and paste from other apps *into* my notebooks, but how do I copy/paste code *out* of notebook into a different app?

I'm accessing a Linux VNC session via Chicken.  I can cut/paste with wild abandon between OSX/Linux using both command X/C/V and/or middle mouse button.  I can also copy code *into* IPython notebook.  I'm stopped dead in my tracks trying to get code *out* of IpyNotebook.

Using Notebook's 'Edit/Copy Cell' doesn't work, neither does 'Ctrl-m c'.

I'm running IPython 0.13.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to select and copy code using normal Ctrl-C Ctrl-V. 'Edit/Copy Cell' is a specific action in javascript that does a little more and that browser security policy prevent us to bind with clipboard.

Comment: CONTROL!  Where have you been all my last 3 hours?!?  If only I'd thought to look in the *browser's* Edit menu...   Thanks Matt!

Comment: Sometime, Problem Exist between chair and Keyboard.... :-), I think the issue was with keyboard, while you posted the question, the keyboard firmware update added added keys that weren't there before.

Comment: Aren't *all* the problems between the chair and the keyboard? :-)

Comment: Nop, other are in the OS. Enven if using the term OS for that is really exaggerated.